# Installing MySQL on Amazon EC2 Instance, backup?

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2

To install MySQL on Amazon EC2 Instance (for example: t3.medium), is there anything I need to be aware of when doing snapshot backup of EC2 Instance?

What is the right procedure to install MySQL on EC2 and regular backup of MySQL Database and EC2 Backup?

I know RDS is an option but I like to avoid that to reduce monthly cost.

Edit: Linux centos and don't need replication setup. It is a web server with php and apache.

Comment: The right procedure to install MySQL is going to depend on your specific needs and setup. You haven't even told us if it'll be on Windows or Linux, let alone stuff like multi-server replication etc. RDS may be expensive, but so's screwing up your DB setup or backups - you should re-consider it if you're asking this broad of a question.

Comment: Updated my topic.

Answer (score 3):

You should read about [crash consistent vs application consistent](https://n2ws.com/blog/ebs-snapshot/ebs-snapshots-crash-consistent-vs-application-consistent) snapshots.

EBS snapshots are crash consistent. The volume can be inconsistent if the EC2 instance is writing to the volume, but in general snapshots will usually be consistent and you should usually be able to restore the volume / database from a snapshot without issue. However, "usually" is something you need to test and validate based on your requirements - if this is a critical database that changes frequently you'll need to be more careful.

My approach is to run mysqldump daily using a cron job, which I back up to S3 using the same cron job, and is also captured as part of my snapshots. This gives me confidence I can restore my database even if the EBS snapshot isn't 100% consistent.

Install mysql as per normal, there are hundreds of tutorials and plenty of documentation about that, and it depends on your OS. I have mysql on a t2.nano along with Nginx / PHP, with the MySQL performance schema turned off it works well given the low load of the server. I have 512MB of swap in addition to the 512MB RAM, only a little of that swap is ever used.

Comment: Great answer, thank you. What is your thought having separate ESB for mysql Data?

Comment: If you mean a separate EBS volume, I guess there are advantages and disadvantages. Main disadvantage is EBS performance scales with volume size, so by having everything on one volume you'll get more IOPS. I can't really see any significant advantages, other than being able to attach that volume to another instance in future if you need to - one EBS volume can only attach to one instance at a time though.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't do snapshots to backup MySQL. If you just take a snapshot from a live MySQL instance most likely it will be corrupt. There is a workaround though - before taking the snapshot you can lock the tables with `FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK`. In that case MySQL will still have to do crash recovery (by the way, we're talking about InnoDB, right?) but the database will be consistent after that. [mylvmbackup](https://www.lenzg.net/mylvmbackup/) uses this method.

Percona Xtrabackup and mysqldump are proper tools to take backups from MySQL. They both have pros and cons so it's up to you which one to pick.
In my opinion Xtrabackup is more universal tool as it works on large databases where mysqldump shows unacceptably long restore time.

I can recommend to use [TwinDB Backup](https://github.com/twindb/backup) (disclaimer I'm the author) that uses Xtrabackup plus implements retention policy, scheduling, streaming to S3, encryption, backups verification - all features that are missing in Xtrabackup but constitute a proper backup solution. It's also free and opensource.